# How to apply css class to an element but exclude nested/child element of the same style

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to to apply style to a body element but the style should not affect a nested element specified by a selector. I tried with `:not` but it seems not working for children elements.
Here is my example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body:not(.not-disabled) {
  color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>

  <p class="not-disabled">This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="not-disabled">This is another paragraph.</p>
  <button class="not-disabled">Enabled</button>
  <button>Disabled</button>
  <div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect the paragraphs not to be transparent. Also both buttons are disabled but I would like to have one of them enabled, namely: **Ebabled**, but my expectations turned out not to be correct.

Is there any way to do this?
Please don't judge me too harsh. I am new to CSS and I googled but couldn't find a solution. Probably as a newbie, my questions are wrong.

Comment: Remove `body` from your selector. You're targeting the body with your selector not everything within it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`body:not(.not-red)` means that the style should apply to a body element that has not the `.not-red` class.

What you are looking for is applying this style to the children of the body, so add a space to the selector `body :not(.not-red)`

```css
body :not(.not-red) {
/*  ^ note the space here */
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p class="not-red">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="not-red">This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

As an alternative you can override the style, since the stylesheet will be 'read' from above to under.

```css
body {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.not-red {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p class="not-red">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="not-red">This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

Comment: Apologize, I mislead you with the first post. Please see the updated content.

Comment: Your CSS might have been changed a bit, but the principal remains the same...

Comment: Please run the snippet. All the elements are disabled and the opacity stays the same

Comment: Again, the principal is the same. Add a space between body and the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the desired color to your `not-red` class

```
body {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.not-red {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Styles work in a cascading fashion. You can set the color in the `body` element as a default and then specify a different color for specific elements, if you so choose.

Comment: I edited my original post. I apologize  I mislead you with a wrong example of my problem :(